# Barcode printing & scanning

Tags: axapta, barcode-scanner, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

Dynamics AX 2012 provides barcode integration only in retail module, can I somehow enable this functionality in other areas, as in, I want to attach a barcode with item and then transfer inventory from one warehouse to other by scanning the barcode.

Please guide.

Comment: Is this a programming problem? a barcode scanner just reads bars as characters, so you can use one to write an email if you really want to. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You will need an item bar code report. Look on SSRS report `WMSLocationLabel` to see how it is done.

The scanning requires a bar code scanner (surprise). If your cursor is at item number field your scanner will input the item number when scanned.